Calculate Levene test in R
I'm trying to calculate the Levene tests with multiple interactions.
Herbivore   Treatment   Level   Evenness
N   C   C   0.796
S   U   L   0.780
G   U   L   0.833
C   U   L   0.757
S   U   H   0.819
G   U   H   0.820
C   U   H   0.882


install.packages("car") 
library(car)
levene_test <- leveneTest(Eveness ~ Herbivore * Treatment * Level, data = data)

But I got this as response:
Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
      Df F value Pr(>F)
group  6     NaN    NaN
       0   

I checked the data. Evenness is considered as a numeric value. I created a frame with the provided data but I got the same error.
I used chatGPT but it is providing the same code. Impossible to know where the problem is...

This is probably related to your sample size and number of variables to test, resulting in a number of degrees of freedom that make the result impossible to compute

Just focusing on evenness and treatment, it seems that you have one value for treatment C. So, you can't say anything about the variability of evenness for that treatment. That alone would seem to be fatal to what you're asking.

The "not a number" values you are getting (indicated as NaN) are a major clue, and Nick already noted in the comments why that is. The first row seems to have observations that are only unique to that row...N, C, and C only appear in their respective columns once. Thus the groupings under question cannot actually vary meaningfully. As a quick test of this, we can just inspect the data visually to see this in action:
#### Load Data ####
d <- read.table(
  textConnection(
    "
    N   C   C   0.796
    S   U   L   0.780
    G   U   L   0.833
    C   U   L   0.757
    S   U   H   0.819
    G   U   H   0.820
    C   U   H   0.882
    "
  )
)

colnames(d) <- c("Herbivore","Treatment","Level","Evenness")
d

#### Plot ####
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Treatment,
             y=Evenness))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(title="Variation in Treatment")

Notice that the treatment group "C" only has a single line because it doesn't actually vary at all:

It may be good to figure out why this is the case. Perhaps this row can be simply excluded if it doesn't provide any meaningful input, along with selecting a more limited model accordingly (using just herbivore and level).
